# How do I convert Shopify API json into a readable dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, shopify-api

I have the following Python 3.7 code to extract order data from the Shopify Admin API in json format and format into a pandas dataframe.

```
r = requests.get('https://%s:%s@%s.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-01/orders.json?status=any' % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, SHOP_NAME))
d1 = r.json()

df = pd.json_normalize(d1)
print(df)
```

Currently, my output looks the below:
[image]

However, my desired output looks like this:
[image]

For reference, d1 looks like the following:
`{'orders': [{'id': 30001, 'email': 'test@gmail.com', 'closed_at': None,...`

Should I be using a function other than `json.normalize()` to achieve my desired output? I've also tried using `json.dumps()` to format between dictionary vs. string but I haven't had any success there.

Comment: Can you post what `d1` looks like?

Comment: @AlexF - just updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, pretty simple actually. You just need to access the `order` key to get the values dictionary you want a `pd.DataFrame` from.

Here is some sample code

```
import pandas as pd
import json

d = {
    'orders': [
        {'id': 3111498449045, 'email': 'test@gmail.com', 'closed_at': None},
        {'id': 3111498449046, 'email': 'test@gmail.com', 'closed_at': None},
        {'id': 3111498449047, 'email': 'test@gmail.com', 'closed_at': None}
    ]
}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d['orders'])
```

---

To fix your code you should do:

```
r = requests.get('https://%s:%s@%s.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-01/orders.json?status=any' % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, SHOP_NAME))
d1 = r.json()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d['orders'])
print(df)
```

Comment: That worked for the most part. However a later field titled total_shipping_price_sent (which was not shown in my example) is returned as the following: ```{'shop_money': {'amount': '10.00', 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': '10.00', 'currency_code': 'USD'}}```.

How can I parse out just the amount under shop_money?

Comment: You need to do preprocessing on the json dictionary to only extract `shop_money['amount']` before converting to the dataframe. If you want to publish a longer json in the description I can take a look.

Comment: @markellefultz20 could you accept my answer?